# How do I return back to the main c file from the .h file?

Tags: c

Im making a game with multiple modes. I compiled the the different modes into an h file so that I can just insert a header in the main c file. The main c file only contains the main menu. In the h file I made, I ask user if they want to play again or not. If they choose yes, it'll loop and restart the game however, if they choose no, it will exit. How do I make it that if the user chooses no, it will return to the main function in the main c file?

```
void nextround()
{
    printf("\n\t\tWant to play again??? [y/n]:  ");
    char c;
    scanf("\n%c", &c);
    if (c == 'y')
    {
        resetgame();
        multiplayer();
    } else
    {
        // how to return to the main c file??
    }
```

The code above is located in the h file btw

Comment: [Don't define functions in header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242357/why-cant-i-define-plain-c-functions-in-header-file)

Comment: What happens if you just let your function exit?

Comment: @MarkSouls what do you mean by dont define the func??

Comment: @StephenNewell it will just exit like any normal program. I want to that if the user chooses not to play again, it will go back to the main c file function and display again the main menu

Comment: One thing at a time. Don't worry about how to divide the code into two files until you understand what *functions* do. A function is not a program. When the function call terminates, control returns to the code that called the function, which in this case is `main`.

Comment: ```main``` called, say, ```startgame``` function. Then ```startgame``` called ```nextround```. When ```nextround``` ends, program will return to ```startgame``` exactly where it called ```nextround```. Then when ```startgame``` ends, program will return to ```main``` exactly where it called ```startgame```.

Comment: @MarkSouls void multiplayer(){ multigame(); nextround();} so i cant do this?

Comment: I defined multiplayer in the c file then the multigame and the nextround is in h file

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of all your files.

Comment: "I compiled the the different modes into an h file" please elaborate or show that. I do not get it. Compiling is a very misleading expression here.

Comment: Please state which of the following concepts you are already familiar with: loops; building from multiple code files; functions; return statements; function prototypes; variable definitions in contrast to variable declarations; problems when including headers with code; ....

Comment: With some indentation (using my favorite style, feel free to adapt to yours) it is apparent that the shown code is missing the final closing `}`. Is that a copy paste error from creating the question or is your actual code really also missing that?

Comment: Your code example doesn't say much, some more details about how you are trying to achieve the different states would be helpful. Search for `game loops`, `game states` to learn more

Answer (score 1):

> void multiplayer(){ multigame(); nextround();} so i cant do this?

In order to do it right - without inappropriate recursions -, you don't call `multiplayer` in `nextround`. Instead, you change them to e. g.:

```
int nextround()
{
    …
    if (c == 'y')
    {
        resetgame();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void multiplayer()
{
    do multigame(); while (nextround());
}
```